# Database syncing issue (Caching+Thread)

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, magicalrecord

I am trying to sync my database(core data) with server. I am using Magicalrecord(https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) for my core data operations.

I am uploading files to server synchronously in background. While this operations are running in background user can add/delete/update files.

At first try, i used **MR_contextForCurrentThread** and **MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait** for DB operations. Problem with this is i am getting duplicate data even though data is synced but not updated for queue. I found reason here that there is some caching on thread and data is not yet saved in main thread so current thread keeps returning old data.

On second, i used **MR_context** and **saveWithBlockAndWait** for DB operations but still getting the same issue.

At last, i used **MR_defaultContext** with any save method then it all worked fine but problem i got here is "**CoreData: error: NULL _cd_rawData but the object is not being turned into a fault**" : threading issue.

Which context or saving method is more suitable when DB operations running in both thread and want every time latest committed data on both threads ?

Should i use one context and make DB operations synchronously ?

Comment: Can you please provide your code?

Comment: I am just saving data with 2 different threads in same entity. Anyway, i tried to remove Magical record and replace it with [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType] and than save child and parent with perform block. But here also facing some weird issue like UI stuck sometimes when i try to run 2/3 perform block in a row.

Comment: Hi, it's really hard for us to decide without seeing the your implementation ie: Code. So, please go ahead and post your code.
Thanks.